# Does WSO2 APIM and EI support API to delete an existing tenant?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

If so which version? Does it support cascading delete operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V 2.x does not support it. V 4.x supports it but not fully - see [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/multitenancy/managing-tenants/).

Warning : If you perform operations such as tenant deletion, even though the tenant details are removed, any data stored in registry, file system, other databases, etc. will not be removed. Such data will need to be removed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Tenant deletion is supported with an admin service as explained here.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/multitenancy/managing-tenants/

All the versions of APIM should have this capability - 2.x, 3.x and 4.0 versions.

The admin service is https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteTenantManagerService?wsdl